# Original route's filters are still applied to a request after changing the route attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using spring cloud gateway for my proxy application. I have a global filter which intercepts incoming requests and checks for certain headers and cookies. If it finds that one of the headers is missing, it will modify the exchange GATEWAY_ROUTE_ATTR and the request URL in order to redirect the request to an error controller in the same proxy application. I am using the yml based route configuration approach. The issue arises when redirecting the request. I modify the route attribute of the ServerWebExchange, but the filters of the old route are still getting applied.

This is the scenario:

1. request comes in for http://some-domain.com/common-prefix/xyz (some downstream service serves this)
2. This URL is matched to one of the routes configured in application.yml, and this route includes a stripPrefix = 1 filter

```
        - id: original_route
          uri: http://some-domain.com/
          predicates:
            - Path=/common-prefix/xyz/**
          filters:
            - StripPrefix=1
```

3. The request is missing a header so the request URL is rewritten to http://my-proxy-domain/error
   The GATEWAY_ROUTE_ATTR is also modified so that the matched route is now

```
        - id: error_redirect
          uri: http://my-proxy-domain/
          predicates:
            - Path=/error
          filters:
            - RedirectTo=302, http://my-proxy-domain/error
```

4. I now expect the request to be sent to http://my-proxy-domain/error, where some error message will be put in the response body and a 4xx code is returned.

what actually happens is that /error is stripped and the request is redirected to http://my-proxy-domain

this is the code that actually modifies the request and route

```
    private ServerWebExchange redirectToErrorController(String reason){
        logger.error(reason);
        String requestURI = request.getURI().toString();
        logger.info("Original request URL: {}", requestURI);
        addOriginalRequestUrl(exchange, request.getURI());
        String url = UriComponentsBuilder
                .fromHttpUrl(ProxyApplicationUtility.getDomainName(requestURI))
                .path("/redirect" + ERROR_PATH).build().toUriString();


        logger.info("redirecting to {}",url );

        ServerHttpRequest request1 = request.mutate().uri(URI.create(url)).build();
        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FOUND);
        response.getHeaders().set("status", "302");
        response.getHeaders().add("Location", url);
        exchange.getAttributes().put(GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR, request.getURI());
        exchange.getAttributes().put(GATEWAY_ROUTE_ATTR, getErrorRoute());
        exchange = exchange.mutate().request(request1).response(response).build();
        return exchange;

    }

//this method gets the error route from a RouteLocator bean that contains a list of defined routes //for the application
    private Route getErrorRoute(){
        Flux<Route> routeFlux = routeLocator.getRoutes();
        List<Route> routeList = routeFlux.collectList().block();
        for(Route route: routeList){
            if("error_redirect".equals(route.getId())){
                return route;
            }
        }

        return null;

    }
```

It seems like the StripPrefix filter I have in the original_route is still being applied once the global filter is done with its processing and send the request on, even though I have changed the route being applied

How can I make sure that only the filters associated with my new route are being applied?